# How to Configure "Reboot instead of Shutdown"

Tags: windows

I was searching google and serverfault but didn't find anything close to a solution.

We have a remote accessed W2012R2 Server which we need to reboot pretty often. But some Users are thinking when they are told to reboot it, it is the same as doing a shutdown and then the next user wonders why he can't connect after the reboot.

I want to achieve that they cant hit *log off* or *shutdown* but the can choose *reboot*. They won't cope with Command Prompt or anything. And via GPO I have only found how to "remove shutdown restart sleep and hibernate" and "remove log off". These do not achieve what I need.

I thought as workaround I could make an exe which restarts and disable all other options but maybe there is a more elegant way of doing it.

Thank you for any Answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a special application, you can use a batch/powershell script using [`shutdown.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown), for example: `shutdown -r -t 60 -c "Will shut down in 60s"`. Place that script on the Desktop or Taskbar or whatever you need.

Or for Powershell you can use [`Restart-Computer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-computer?view=powershell-6).

Comment: I would add a confirmation prompt to the batch/script so people have to press `Y` to actually reboot, otherwise users may reboot the server accidentally.

Comment: But is there a possibilty to let windows reboot when they press shutdown? If not I will definitly take use of powershell but the problem here is to teach them to press now this instead of that what will remain in the same issue again.

Comment: Just disable shutdown and restart via GPO, so they can only reboot using the script